# como criar e escrever arquivo txt com fopen em um pasta em rede

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe um formar de criar , escrever um arquivo `txt` com em uma pasta localizada fora da aplicação do PHP, em outra maquina na mesma rede . O servidor PHP esta em linux Ubuntu e tenho que salvar em um outro servidor Windows. Como o PHP não tem suporte ao SMB como  posso fazer isto?

```
fopen("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Enviamos\\file00001.txt",'w+'); local esta ok e em outro diretório em rede 
fopen("\\192.168.10.4\\Enviamos\\file00001.txt",'w+')
```

Comment: Veja se serve [Usando arquivos remotos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.remote-files.php)

Answer (score -2):

Exemplo simples de uma execução dessa tarefa.

```
<?php
// Caminho do arquivo na rede
$filename = "//10.96.1.100/Pasta/Na/Rede/Arquivo.txt";
// Modo de leitura e escrita
$mode = "w+";
// Inicializar o recurso de leitura e escrita do arquivo
$handle = fopen($filename, $mode);
// escreva no arquivo - forma 1
$arrayStr = join("", [
    "Data;Valor" . PHP_EOL, // Coloca os dados e uma quebra de linha
    "23/10/2020;1.500,55" . PHP_EOL // Coloca os dados e uma quebra de linha
]);

printf("Escrevi %s bytes no arquivo %s <br>", fwrite($handle, $arrayStr), $filename);
// Fechar arquivo
fclose($handle);
```